# Error al crear un servidor local con xampp

Tags: apache

Buen día.
Tengo un problema al momento de hacer un servidor local, he modificado los siguientes archivos para que funcionen, pero aún así no me funciona.
El primer archivo que modifiqué es:

```
    httpd-vhosts.conf
```

en el cual lo que agregué fue lo siguiente:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
 DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
 ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


 <VirtualHost *:8080>
 ServerAdmin host@dev.local.s.org
 DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/s"
 ServerName dev.local.s.org
 ErrorLog "logs/dev.local.s-error.log"
 CustomLog "logs/dev.local.s-access.log"common 
 </VirtualHost>
```

El segundo archivo que modifiqué es el siguiente

```
           hosts
```

Este esta ubicado en la ruta de Windows/System32/drivers/etc

y solo agregue el siguiente host

```
    127.0.0.1   dev.local.s.org
```

pero al intentar ingresar a la ruta me aparece lo siguiente:

Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

No se si tenga algo que ver el que tenga el puerto 8080 activado, en lugar del 80 que esta por defecto.

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Validaste que en el archivo C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf esté comentada la línea "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" y asegurate también de descomentar en el mismo archivo la línea "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so". Si no te funciona avisa y lo reviso bien.

Comment: Lo hice, pero aun aparece el error 404.

Comment: Entrando a dev.local.s.org:8080 arroja el mismo error?

Comment: Si, aprece lo mismo